# Sound not working on MacBook Pro 13 Mid 2012

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, bluetooth

I bought a Macbook Pro 13' Mid 2012 with the sound damaged just for work (I develop IOS apps) but now I miss the sound in my Mac and I want to fix it.

The sound icon in the superior bar does not appear and when I go to sound settings. I found this message: "No output devices found".  Sound works correctly with bluetooth headsets.

Is there a way to fix this problem?  Does this mac allow for the sound card to be replaced?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I have the same issue with my MBP I try all the software tricks but nothing work, now I'm using external sound adapter for using headphone there is no an other option I found.